# Bluetooth not working after reinstalling Windows 10 on new SSD

Tags: windows-10, ssd, bluetooth, reinstall

I followed the tutorial [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/clean-install-of-windows-10-os-on-new-ssd-best/9186ae98-b2b4-4b7a-b3ff-0b053ce2d1c9) to re-install Windows 10 on a new SSD of my desktop. Specifically, I utilized the Media Creation Tool. The new system works well except for Bluetooth connectivity. When I click on "add a device", the system scans but no available device is shown. I confirmed that my Bluetooth speaker is visible using laptop.

I tried:
Updating drivers, restarting Bluetooth services in device manager etc.

I didn't encounter this issue when I was using the system on the old SSD.

What would be a viable solution? Is there a way to clone the old system entirely to a new SSD?

Thank you.

Comment: You might need to remove the device from the Bluetooth connection list and re-pair it. See https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/fix-connections-to-bluetooth-audio-devices-09ba2fb1-9472-9259-bd05-9306dd839f21

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. However, since it's a fresh install on the new SSD, my device is not already connected.